# Return One Row from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, row, unique, fetch

Amateur question, but something I've been wondering about.  What is the PHP for selecting one row from a MySQL query?  AKA you're picking something by unique ID (you know there's only one row that matches your request) and want to get only that value.  Do you still have to use a while loop and mysql_fetch_row?

```
$query = "SELECT name,age FROM people WHERE uid = '2'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// what php is used to return the name and age?  preferably without a loop?
```

Comment: As stated in the PHP manual for the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `limit 0,1` and for PHP 7 use **mysqli**

```php
$query = "SELECT name,age FROM people WHERE uid = '2' LIMIT 0,1";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $res["age"];
```

Comment: Editor's Note: I approved the edit to change `mysql` to `mysqli` because the `mysql` function has been deprecated from PHP7, the current lowest supported version.  For time travelers who still use PHP5, the `mysql` is the correct function.

Answer (score 2):

If `uid` is your primary key, or it has a `unique` constraint, you can simply call `mysql_fetch_row($res)` once.

If you want to verify that you actually got a result, you can check if `mysql_num_rows($res) == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any loop required, just call the function to extract one row from a Query Resultset:

```
$query = "SELECT name,age FROM people WHERE uid = '2'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
var_dump( $row );
```

Comment: I did not added any limit because using a Primary Key as filter(as it is in this specific case), using the Limit is just redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Add **[`LIMIT`](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)** in your query. For instance,

```
SELECT name,age FROM people WHERE uid = '2' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

*Here is another example:*

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("server","user","password")
    or die ('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error() ); 
    //
    mysql_select_db ("database")
    or die ('Selection failed: ' . mysql_error());
    //
    $portaQuery = "SELECT user_name FROM table_users";
    //
    $portaResult = mysql_query($portaQuery) 
    or die ('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    //
    $displayUserName = mysql_result ($portaResult, 0, "user_name" );
    //
    echo $displayUserName;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this code. This will return an object with all the property.

`fetch_object` => Returns the current row of a result set as an object

```
$sql = "SELECT * from contacts where id=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$allData =$result -> fetch_object();
var_dump($allData);
```

2. Use this code. This will return an associative array

`fetch_assoc` => Fetch a result row as an associative array

```
$sql = "SELECT * from contacts where id=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$allData =$result -> fetch_assoc();
var_dump($allData);
```

You can use `fetch_assoc` or `fetch_object` according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_fetch_assoc** this extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead use **mysqli_fetch_assoc** - this will fetch a result row as an associative array.

**Example 1: Object oriented style**

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['Name'];
```

**Example 2: Procedural style**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 1";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
/* fetch associative array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['Name'];
}
```